# How to iterate on map of linkedlist in spring view

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have write the following code to return model to `spring view(jsp)`.But i am unable to rotate over the model.

Can any body help me.

Here's example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/news", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getNewsView() {
        ModelAndView modelNView = new ModelAndView();
        modelNView.setViewName("/content/news");
        Criterion activeCrit = Restrictions.eq("active", true);
        Criterion typeCrit = Restrictions.eq("type", tsService.findByCode(ContentType.class, "NEWS_TYPE"));
        List<Content> matches = (List<Content>)tsService.findMatches(Content.class, Order.desc("createDateTime"), 3, activeCrit, typeCrit);

        LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>> mapList = new LinkedList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        for(Content matcher : matches){
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id", matcher.getId().toString());
            map.put("name", matcher.getName());
            map.put("description", matcher.getDescription());
            mapList.add(map);
        }
        modelNView.addObject("model", mapList);
        return modelNView;
    }
```

When i called this model and jsp it show the will.I used the following code for this.

```
${model}
```

but again unable how to print like this if i have following data in list

1 naveen 'this is just example'

2 parveen 'desc'

Comment: Could we see your JSP code that iterates over the LinkedList please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a forEach loop in your jsp which iterates through each 'map' in the 'model'.

For example,

```
<c:forEach items="${model}" var="map">
     <div>
         ${map.name} <br/>
         ${map.description}
     <div/>
</c:forEach>
```